# Generic Array Error for what appears to be not a Generic Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, templates, generics

I'm getting the generic array error but I don't think I'm trying to instantiate a generic array. The array is of type Double, which means it shouldn't be generic, no?

```
public class PolynomialSet extends Set<Polynomial<Double>>{
    public PolynomialSet(int size){
        elements = new Polynomial<Double>[size];
}

public class Polynomial <Domain> {}

public class Set<Type> {

    protected Type[] elements;
    protected int cardinality;

    public int size(){
        return elements.length;
    }
    public Type get(int k){
        return elements[k];
    }
    public void set(int k, Type in){
        elements[k]=in;
    }

}
```

Comment: `new Polynomial<Double>[size]` would be a generic array. You are trying to instantiate a generic array. What are you actually trying to do here? Are you trying to specify the length of `elements`?

Comment: [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104)

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm trying to instantiate "elements" as an array of "Polynomial<Double>" of length "size".

Comment: @user2303321 an array where the element type is `Polynomial<Double>` would be a generic array.

Comment: @AndyTurner Does the template <Double> make it generic? Can I make it not generic while still allowing Polynomial<Domain> to have its template?

Comment: @AndyTurner Isn't it generic if the memory isn't allocated at compilation? I thought that having Polynomial<Double> would allocate the memory of a double.